# grep multiple files through tail

Tags: grep, tail

Trying to grep a phrase out of multiple files as they are constantly populated (logs), but with hint as to which file was updated with the phrase.

For example:

```
grep bindaddr /vservers/*/var/log
```

gets me:

```
/vservers/11010/var/log:bindaddr=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
/vservers/12525/var/log:bindaddr=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
/vservers/12593/var/log:bindaddr=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Which is cool, but I need this for tail -f.

```
tail -fn 100 /vservers/*/var/log | grep bindaddr
```

gets me the lines needed but no indicator in which file, so I need a mix of the two.

Comment: See the accepted solution at:
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195922/show-filename-at-begining-of-each-line-when-tailing-multiple-files-at-once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `-v` in `tail`, you get a verbose mode: from `man tab` --> "always output headers giving file names". This way, whenever something happens in a file, you will get the header on the preceding line.

Together with this, you can use `grep -B1` to show the match + the previous line.

All together, this should do:

```
tail -fvn 100 /vservers/*/var/log | grep -B1 bindaddr
```

#### Test

Doing this in one tab:

```
$ echo "hi" >> a2
$ echo "hi" >> a2
$ echo "hi" >> a1
$ echo "hi" >> a2
```

I got this in the other one:

```
$ tail -vfn 100 /tmp/a* | grep -B1 "h"
==> /tmp/a1 <==

==> /tmp/a2 <==
hi
hi

==> /tmp/a1 <==
hi

==> /tmp/a2 <==
hi
```

Comment: I see a fluctuating +1 :) Let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: I would gladly +1, but I dont have the Rep for it. Yes this has provided an acceptable output. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this to put the filename in the front of each line from `tail`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Arrange to kill all descendants on exit/interrupt
trap "kill 0" SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT
for f in *.txt; do
    tail -f "$f" | sed "s/^/"$f": /" > /dev/tty &
done
# grep in stdin (i.e. /dev/tty)
grep bina -
```

Answer (score 0):

I think some people are coming to this post looking for a way to display the filename while grepping the tail of multiple files:

```
for f in path/to/files*.txt; do echo $f; tail $f | grep 'SEARCH-THIS';  done;
```

This will display an output like this

```
filename1.txt
 search result 1
 search result 2

filenam2.txt
 search result 3
 search result 4

...
```